# Write the function as a combination of elementary functions

Tags: function-and-relation-composition

$2xe ^{(-4x^2)}$

Is this correct?

$f(x) = -4x^2, g(x) = e^x, h(x) = 2x$

$h(x)\cdot g(f(x))$

Comment: @GPerez No I don't

Comment: My bad, awful mistake, deleted to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1):

We are given that

$$f(x) = -4x^2, \quad g(x) = e^x, \quad h(x) = 2x$$

Here is how to express $h(x) \cdot g(f(x))$ that as a combination of elementary functions.

$$\begin{aligned}
h(x) \cdot g(f(x)) &= 2x \cdot e^{f(x)}\\
&= 2x \cdot e^{-4x^2}
\end{aligned}$$

If we have $h(g(f(x)))$, then

$$\begin{aligned}
h(g(f(x))) &= 2g(f(x))\\
&= 2e^{f(x)}\\
&= 2e^{-4x^2}
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: I made up the f(x) g(x) and h(x) so they weren't given. I don't understand the last step. What happened to the 2x?

Comment: $x$ is being substituted with $g(f(x))$